# Ajax & Jquery- heading of a table turn into a dropdown list

Tags: jquery, ajax, html-table

I have a HTML table that has headings.

Does anyone know of a JQuery script/plugin that when you click the heading of the table, the heading turns into a dropdown whereby you can select a value from the dropdown (populated through AJAX)?

Comment: Something similar to the Excel filter I suppose- where their is an arrow, and when it is clicked, drops down a list.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to give [datatables](http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html) a try